# Can't get userID from session express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I'm trying to catch the user ID from a current session so I can make a delete profile function.
I'm using express with express-sessions, mongoose, passport.

The code i'm using to delete a user does work, i've copied id's from my mongo db into the code and they deleted just fine. The problem must be catching the ID.

I can actually retrieve the user ID when using this piece of code in one of my .pug files:

ID: #{user.id}  //outputs: "5cf51df175eb3842c461f9ae"

I've got the project on my github @ https://github.com/LarsBreuren/Muzika

This is my delete function that gives the error: "Cannot read property '_id' of undefined". When i insert an ID from my mongoDB in the const id it works just fine, so my guess is that the req.session.user._id is invalid

```
router.get('/delete', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.session.user._id
  User.findOneAndRemove({_id: id }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).send()
    } else {
      console.log('User removed')
      return res.status(200).send()
    }
  })
})
```

These are snippets i use for my passport:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

And this is my session setup:

```
app.use(session({
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: 'ilikecats',
}));
```

I'm hoping to get the User's ID in the const id so i can delete the logged in profile. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot read property '_id' of undefined" suggests that 'user' is not an element of 'session' in the request object, or the value you are expecting is not coming through with your request. I would suggest running a debugger and viewing what is in the request object at the line where you are declaring your constant. You should see that the data is not coming through the way you think it is. From there you can compare the data you are receiving and the data you're expecting and adjust your input.

Hope this helps in some way. :)

Comment: I'll go and try to find if the data get trough correctly. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this isn't exactly the solution you're looking for, but it is an alternative solution to this problem. In my application view,  I asked the user to input their email in order to confirm they want to delete their account.

```
In the front-end: 'removeUser.ejs'

<form action="/removeuser" method="POST">
   <label>E-mail</label> 
      <input type="text" name="email">
    <br>
  <button type="submit">Eliminar Usuario</button>
</form>
```

//And this is the controller that gets the input from my view:

```
const User = require('../models/User')

module.exports = async(req, res) => {
   const user = await User.findOneAndDelete({email:req.body.email}, 
(err) => {  
  if(err) {
    console.log(err)
  res.redirect('/removeUser')
      }
  })
  res.redirect('/')  
}
```

So instead of trying to catch the user ID from a current session, you get the e-mail from user, which is also unique in your DB if you have set up your User Schema properly.

I hope this helps, 
Cheers